# How to compare records in a SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table name TransactionTable. If InsuranceCode = 'ADAP' and IsADAP = 1, I have to filter these records and return the remaining records.

I am trying to write something similar to this syntax.

```
select *  from TransactionTable
where  Not Exists
(select * from TransactionTable where InsuranceCode = 'ADAP' and IsADAP = 1 )
```

Total records in TransactionTable is 1832 and Total records on filtration criteria is 109. I expect 1723 records as output. Below syntax returns only 785 records. I am aware that below syntax is incorrect.

```
select * from TransactionTable 
where InsuranceCode <> 'ADAP' and IsADAP <> 1
```

How to compare a table records and get the output.

Comment: You are not explaining clearly what it is what you want. As written, then the answer provided by RBarry is correct. If that's **not** what you want then please update your question explaining clearly what it is what you actually want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
select * from TransactionTable 
where (InsuranceCode <> 'ADAP' or IsADAP <> 1)
```

Lookup [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) if you want to understand why.

Note that the above has the same meaning as this version: (disregarding NULLs)

```
select * from TransactionTable 
where NOT (InsuranceCode = 'ADAP' and IsADAP = 1)
```

.. which is because of DeMorgan's laws.

Comment: No sir, Condition to filter is InsuranceCode = ADAP and IsADAP = 1. If both column values are above mentioned, just filter it. OR Syntax will return the records even if they both dont match

Comment: do you want to return the records having InsuranceCode = ADAP and IsADAP = 1

Comment: @goofyui  Do what I said and lookup DeMorgan's laws, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws.

Comment: @RBarryYoung You should probably add parenthesis to the first OR condition, to avoid future errors if someone later adds a condition to the where without noticing the OR